# How to use TO HINDER, TO HAMPER?

Tags: verbs

1 He hampered/hindered my studying English yesterday.

2 He hampered/hindered me in studying English yesterday.

3 He hampered/hindered me to study English yesterday.

I think 1 is OK 2 might be OK 3 must be WRONG. Do you agree?

Comment: Was #3 written by an Australian?

Comment: No, my fantasy.

Comment: Just FYI, they don't mean exactly the same thing. Hamper is specifically relating to hindering movement or progress, whereas hinder can just be used wherever something/someone is is stopping anything happen. It's a very subtle difference but when it doubt hinder is more general.

Answer (score 1):

To me, the verb *hamper* is rather less common, and means specifically to hinder a **physical** activity, probably not intentionally. So I would not use *hamper* there.

Even *hinder* is a bit literary: I think most people would say "He made it hard for me to study yesterday", or "he stopped me studying"; or be more specific, eg "He got in the way" or "He distracted me".

Grammatically, 1 and 2 are both fine, but 1 is a bit stilted nowadays.